# Api-platform mongoldb usage without having postgress in docker-compose

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, docker-compose, api-platform.com

I am able to configure usage of ODM and Mongodb with api-platform using [official doc](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/mongodb/). But you still need to define service for postgress (and have orm dependencies installed), otherwise on startup app waits for db and fails on timeout:

```bash
php_1         | Waiting for database to be ready...
php_1         | Still waiting for database to be ready... Or maybe the database is not reachable. 59 attempts left.
php_1         | Still waiting for database to be ready... Or maybe the database is not reachable. 58 attempts left.
```

Here is databases part of `docker-compose`:

```yaml
  database:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=api
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
      - POSTGRES_USER=api-platform
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # you may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./api/docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    expose:
      - 5433

  db-mongodb:
    # In production, you may want to use a managed database service
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=api
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=api-platform
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mongodb/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/mongodb/data:rw
    ports:
      - 27017
```

Any hints what should I change in my configuration to be able to delete `database` service? I want to keep my setup clean.

Comment: Would be great to get some advice from @dunglas, if he won't come with some suggestions, I will accept "entrypoint" solution.

Comment: I didn't see the php service in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `php` service is started before the `db-mongodb` service.

The `depends_on` options is not fix this that problem.

Check https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

The simplified version of solution above is to add `mongo-db` entrypont:

```
# wait 5 seconds to start mongo in container
while :; do echo '.'; sleep 5 ; done
```

Comment: Yea, modifying entrypoint helps to fix the initial question problem, but there are still some symfony errors. I will update the question a bit later, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to `https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/main/docker-compose.yml` by default
`php` service `depends_on:` `database` service. Try removing that line or replacing it with your `db-mongodb` service and then remove `database` service definition from your docker-compose.yaml.

`depends_on` is used to control starting and shutting down containers in the correct order according to defined dependencies, you can find more info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

Comment: Yes, of course I did it - there seems nothing to do with `docker-compose` - you need to tune up some configuration files, may be removing bundles also.

Comment: @freeek There is an entry in api/docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh between lines 17 and 42 that's responsible for checking database readiness by executing command that seems to specifically use sql: bin/console dbal:run-sql -q "SELECT 1" Perhaps you could try changing that to something mongo oriented if exists. Or use worst solution and remove that part completely. edit: yes the command seems to run arbitrary SQL commands from command line.